# How to group and animate the menus of a dashboard

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dashboard in which I have menus in the left panel of it .Now what I would like to have, is that the menus can be grouped under one i.e under Home menu there may be two or three menus and so on and the menus should be animating capacity also.Here is the picture to illustrate what I would like.

[image]

Here is the CSS that is responsible

```
#doclist {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 98%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#29000000', GradientType=1);
    width:14%;
    overflow: auto;
    border-right: solid 1px #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#doclist ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#doclist li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 4px 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height:19px;
    background: url(../images/right-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 2px;
}
#doclist li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#doclist li a:hover {
    color: #0080FF;
}
#documents {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

and the html section

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="doclist" style="background-color: #fceabb">
        <ul id="documents">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="home" title="Home.jsp">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="details" title="forms/search" id="search">search</a></li>                    
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="newcaller_details" title="forms/newcaller">New Caller</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="newsim_details" title="forms/newsim">Newsim</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trye this jquery solution `http://jsfiddle.net/7zav5/2/`

add below css

```
#documents li ul{
  display:none;
}
```

and script with jquery library

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#documents li ').hover(function(){
      $(this).children('ul').clearQueue();
      $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
  }, 
  function(){
      $(this).children('ul').clearQueue();
      $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
  })  
});
```